# UIView.animateWithDuration going out of the bounds

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to animate some `textfield`. That start animation outside the screen and moving to the center of the screen. But in my case, the animation starts from the center and going out of the `bounds`. That happens when I declaring this in `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear`, but in `viewDidLoad` all work's fine/

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    emailField.center.x -= view.bounds.width
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.4, options: [], animations: {
        self.emailField.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
        }, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try animating the transform property.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    emailField.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-view.bounds.width, 0.0)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.4, options: [], animations: {
        self.emailField.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    }, completion: nil)
}
```